# Grabbing images from mp4 using ffmpeg: How to get image after X seconds

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to grab images from an mp4. The video is 241 seconds long and looking at data from VLC player I can see that the Frame rate is 4.

I would like to grab an image from the video every 5 seconds. Since 241/5 = 48.2 In total I would like to have around 49 images in the end.

How can I do this?

I tried the following simply by trial and error:

```
ffmpeg -i ~/inputvideo.mp4 -r 0.4 -t 240 image-%d.png
```

This gives me a total of 50 images from the video.

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct string would be

```
ffmpeg -i ~/inputvideo.mp4 -vf fps=1/5 image-%d.png
```

thereas fps=1/5 is one Frame every 5 seconds. If you want to create one picture every minute, it would be

```
ffmpeg -i ~/inputvideo.mp4 -vf fps=1/60 image-%d.png
```

**edit** [Here's](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video) also a documentation which seem to suit your needs